# Flood of traffic on port 25

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I am getting thousands of hits on port 25, over 400,000 connections in a day.

I am using sendmail default settings on Debian 7. Mailserver is not configured.

Please see below Nginx access logs

```
root@zone:/usr/local/nginx/logs# tail access.log
61.231.81.100 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:46 +0530] "CONNECT 203.188.197.111:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.82.166 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:46 +0530] "CONNECT 27.123.206.55:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.228.19.219 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:46 +0530] "CONNECT 203.188.197.111:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.83.31 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 114.34.96.143:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.228.19.219 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 203.188.197.119:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.82.166 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 27.123.206.55:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.90.113 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 27.123.206.55:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.84.210 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 203.188.197.111:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.82.166 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 203.188.197.111:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.87.39 - - [12/Sep/2013:23:56:47 +0530] "CONNECT 27.123.206.55:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
```

Now I have blocked entire subnet from Nginx

```
deny 61.231.0.0/16;
deny 61.228.0.0/16;
```

I am getting below access logs:

```
tail access.log
111.241.32.138 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:02 +0530] "GET http://www.google.com.tw/ HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
111.241.32.138 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:02 +0530] "CONNECT mta7.am0.yahoodns.net:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
184.75.210.226 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
61.231.2.232 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:38 +0530] "GET http://www.google.co.jp HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
61.231.2.232 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:39 +0530] "CONNECT mx3.mail2000.com.tw:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.87.103 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:44 +0530] "GET http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
61.231.87.103 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:45 +0530] "CONNECT mta5.am0.yahoodns.net:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.231.83.158 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:55 +0530] "GET http://www.google.com.tw HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
61.231.83.158 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:12:56 +0530] "CONNECT mx3.mail2000.com.tw:25 HTTP/1.0" 400 172 "-" "-"
61.228.22.143 - - [13/Sep/2013:01:13:09 +0530] "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
```

Blocked subnets from iptables, stopped getting traffic from those subnets.

```
-I INPUT -s 61.231.0.0/16 -j DROP
-I INPUT -s 111.241.0.0/16 -j DROP
-I INPUT -s 61.228.0.0/16 -j DROP
 tail access.log
78.40.124.16 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:53:39 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
67.205.67.76 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:54:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
46.165.195.139 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:55:39 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
46.165.195.139 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:55:40 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
174.34.162.242 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:56:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
123.125.71.114 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:56:44 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8553 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
220.181.108.153 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:56:55 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 23153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
95.141.32.46 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:57:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
95.211.217.68 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:58:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
91.109.115.41 - - [13/Sep/2013:02:59:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8078 "-" "Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com)"
```

I think, someone is using my server hostname or IP as SMTP?
Please suggest permanent remedy to resolve this issue, because since this is Client's website and has global access, real user having accessing website from same subnet can be impacted.

How can I stop this?

Comment: Interesting that those are HTTP requests. Are you running a web server and you have possibly inadvertently forwarded port 80 on your router/firewall to port 25 on your server?

Comment: No, it's VPS, I can't access router or firewall. I am seeing this traffic from almost last 7 days. I had only 1 rult in iptables for SMTP `-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT` but now I have modified it drop both INPUT and OUTPUT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not actually receiving traffic on port 25, but on port 80, via your web server.

This traffic is attempting to use your server as a proxy to disguise the origin of the traffic. We generally call such servers open proxies, and they're quite useful for delivering spam and conducting attacks on other sites.

For some reason, some people seem to think your IP address has an open proxy server, but the log entries show that the requests are being refused.

If the volume of requests is too high, I would suggest firewalling off the IP address blocks rather than simply denying them in nginx. For instance:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 61.231.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Comment: Duh. If I would have looked at the log with a little more carefully I would have seen that the traffic is originating FROM port 25.

Comment: Added rules in iptables `-I INPUT -s 61.231.0.0/16 -j DROP
-I INPUT -s 111.241.0.0/16 -j DROP
-I INPUT -s 61.228.0.0/16 -j DROP` still getting traffic from same subnet. I have also blocked traffic on port 25 to my webserver, confirmed by telnet to IP and hostname. I am using CloudFlare free service, only using their DNS.

Comment: Now, checked once again, **not getting traffic** from subnets `61.231.0.0/16, 111.241.0.0/16 and 61.228.0.0/16` Is there any alternative instead of blocking entire subnet from iptables, because it may impact real user who is having IP from those subnets to access my website.

Comment: You could try writing a couple of custom rules for fail2ban.

Comment: Though, all of those requests originate with a single ISP. I might think about contacting that ISP's abuse department.

Comment: Will you suggest example for fail2ban custom rules for this issue.

Comment: It's probably a waste of time as the traffic is harmless, but match the CONNECT query type in your access log and ban the IP at the beginning of the line.  Sending an abuse complaint would just be good citizenship.